# Расположить элементы в определенном порядке

Tags: html, css, css3, блок

Есть блок с картинкой поверх которого находятся квадратные элементы, которые нужно расположить в следующем порядке: слева от картинки блоки скидка и хит, а справа желтый блок и блок с быстрым просмотром, причем любой из блоков  может как присутствовать, так и отсутствовать (если блока со скидкой нет, то на его место сдвигается хит) и картинка не должна смещаться. Внизу картинки текст с ценником и кнопкой добавить в корзину.
Сейчас проблема в следующем: если убрать блок со скидкой, то картинка подпрыгивает вверх, что быть не должно.
Вопрос: как это сделать без правок `html`?  [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/ff5v7ffu/2/)

```css
.product-frame {
  width: 350px;
}
.onsale {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #cd0105;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  color: #faf8e9;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
}
.onfeatured {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #cd0105;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.front {
  top: -38px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.compare {
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #fcdb00;
  border-radius: 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
}
.quick-view {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-frame ">
  <a href="#" class="compare button">Добавить к сравнению</a>
  <span class="onsale">-18%</span>
  <span class="onfeatured"><span>Хит</span></span>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Заполнитель" width="350" class="placeholder" height="150">
  </div>
  <span class="quick-view">q</span>
  <div class="product-section">
    <h3><a href="#">Лодка</a></h3>

    <div class="process-section">
      <div class="price"><span class="amount">10.500&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">a</ruble></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/?add-to-cart=18611" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="18611" data-product_sku="4937" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">В корзину</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.product-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.onsale,
.onfeatured,
.compare {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  float: left;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: red;
}

.compare {
  font-size: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.front img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-frame ">
  <a href="#" class="compare button">Добавить к сравнению</a>
  <span class="onsale">-18%</span>
  <span class="onfeatured"><span>Хит</span></span>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Заполнитель" width="350" class="placeholder" height="150">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-frame ">
  <a href="#" class="compare button">Добавить к сравнению</a>
  <span class="onsale">-18%</span>
  <span class="onfeatured"><span>Хит</span></span>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Заполнитель" width="350" class="placeholder" height="150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но теперь усложнил задачу - привел ее к реальной (картинки могут быть разных размеров, причем под ней блоки с ценой и кнопкой добавить в корзину + блок с быстрым просмотром должен быть  в верхнем углу перед сравнением) - вот это у меня и вызывает затруднения..